# How to trigger jenkins when a git push is attempted to github.com, and allow the push only if the build is successful?

Tags: android, git, github, jenkins, gradle

I have an android project. I want to cinfigure jenkins ci for that. So, my expected workflow is like,

1. Whenever a developer hits git push, the jenkins build should be
   triggered with the new  changes(code shouldn't be pushed to github).
2. If the build is successful in jenkins, then the code should be
   pushed to the github.com.

Please help me. Even if this cannot be achieved in a single run, a work-around (like multiple jenkins jobs or with some temporary branches) to achieve this will also be helpful.

Comment: 1. You should see the jenkins plugin and install the github plugin there is a checkbox to "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub"

Comment: Franck, your are right. but that will push and then trigger the build. I want the build to be triggered before the push process happens.

Comment: In this case I can only suggest to have a branch of dev before merging in your feature branch. I guess if the build is success you can execute a script to merge it on the feature branch. See the plugin Post build task